# Attempting to link a website to my Stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I have recently been working on a website. I just started on it and I can't get the style.css to work. I have done quite harsh digging through the interwebs to search for a solution but I can't look hard enough. To get straight to it, here is my index.html code.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/
fontawesome/4.7.0/css/fontawesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <!-- Load an icon library -->

    <div class="navbar">
    <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a> 
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i> Search</a> 
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a> 
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Login</a>
    </div>
```

So, when I went to my website (halifaxdevelopers.dx.am), I checked Inspect Element and found that for some reason, my  things were moved into my `<body>`.

Anyways, here is my style.css

```
/* Style the navigation bar */
.navbar {
width: 100%;
background-color: #555;
overflow: auto;
}

/* Navbar links */
.navbar a {
float: left;
text-align: center;
padding: 12px;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 17px;
}

/* Navbar links on mouse-over */
.navbar a:hover {
background-color: #000;
}

/* Current/active navbar link */
.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
}

/* Add responsiveness - will automatically display the navbar vertically 
instead of horizontally on screens less than 500 pixels */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.navbar a {
float: none;
display: block;
}
}
```

| I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Your HTML is malformed. Your `<head>` is contained within a `<body>` tag. The correct structure is `<html> <head>...</head> <body>...</body> </html>` - Your elements are being moved around because your browser is attempting to resolve these issues for you. Hopefully this gives you enough to correct the issues - Assuming so, I'm going to submit a closure vote for this question as it seems like a  ***"Simple typographical error"***.

Comment: `linkrel` - try to separate `link` and `rel` on your fontawesome link

Comment: I've fixed that but the website still looks the same. I will edit my question to look like what I have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like the one I have shared below:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Load an icon library -->

  <div class="navbar">
    <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i> Search</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Login</a>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The output will look exactly like this:
[image]

Comment: Okay, I have done that, and the stylesheets show in Inspect Element in <head>, but the style still won't show. You can check it out at halifaxdevelopers.dx.am

Comment: Hi @ConcernedChris can you please check it once again as I can see the code working and the styles affecting the output. 
You can try a different browser or clearing the cache.

Comment: Well it must just be on my side of the screen if you got the output. Alrighty, well I may as well mark you as correct seeing it's right I just can't see it.

Comment: There we go, I cleared my cache and that seemed to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change your `html` structure to something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fontawesome/4.7.0/css/fontawesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
....
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you linked 'stylesheet.css' instead of 'style.css'

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" media="screen"/>
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen"/>
```